# How can I convert a signed jar file to an .exe file and keep it signed?

Tags: java, jar, exe, executable-jar, jar-signing

I have created a JAR file and I've signed it using keytool & jarsigner and then I generated a .exe file, but the .exe does not keep the information of the certificate

How can I convert this .jar to an .exe file without loosing this info?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you converting it to an exe, and why ?

Comment: I've used Launch4j to convert jar to exe. I did that because in contradistinction to .jar, the .exe does not need the JRE. I found in google that the .exe file can be signed using signcode (which is obsolet) or signtool, but it needs the .spc and the .pvk files and I only have the .spc file and a .pem file which I've used to generate the .scp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the only way to do that is signing the generated .exe file.

And here's a guide to do that
http://help.godaddy.com/article/4778?locale=en